# CSS keyframe animation affects div's modal window

Tags: css, animation, modal-dialog, keyframe

I have to add an animation to a fixed position DIV, that contains a modal window.

Without the animation css instruction (`animation:navslide .5s ease forwards;`), the modal window works as expected, occupying the entire screen. However, with the css animation, the modal window shows up inside the fixed position DIV.

Why is the modal window behaving like this? Is there any way for the DIV to have an animation, that does not intrude in the modal window's positioning in the page?

[Here is a demo](https://codepen.io/aslopes/pen/bGwdGxE) of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why do You have modal inside header element - this is wrong. Usually it is best to put modal element in body or other root element. Your demo fixed below.

```
<div class="wrap">

<div class="topHeader">

    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Open Modal</button>


</div>
<div id="id01" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close">close</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla fermentum sagittis ipsum, vitae
            ultrices libero blandit at. Curabitur blandit porta turpis, eu tincidunt tortor ultrices ac. </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pagecontent">
    <h1>A title</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla fermentum sagittis ipsum, vitae ultrices
        libero blandit at. Curabitur blandit porta turpis, eu tincidunt tortor ultrices ac. Phasellus tempus risus
        molestie, porttitor odio eget, varius mi. Nullam rutrum, justo eu sollicitudin gravida, enim quam
        scelerisque enim, id pharetra orci lectus nec magna. Sed imperdiet tortor ex, id pulvinar nulla tincidunt
        vitae. Duis commodo aliquam mi, id pretium eros ornare vitae. Praesent ac nunc eget nisl mattis consectetur
        nec quis orci. Etiam elit nunc, molestie et tortor ac, tristique aliquet metus.</p>
</div>
```

But if You want to keep the modal inside the header I can't help You as there's some overflow conflict in header because of translate.